# Flush Socket blocks the call in non blocking SocketHi

Tags: networking

Hi All
   I am using a non blocking Socket for sending messages.We were getting EGAIN error occassioanally .So I have decided to use Flush(socket) to flush the buffer and make space for new space so that i can avoid EGAIN error .But the problem is Flush(socket) is stuck for indefinite time .

Here is the code

```
 int res = send(socket, buffer, size+lengthSize,0);


 delete buffer; 

 if ( res== -1 ) 

{

 int error = errno;

 cout("ERROR on SendOnPortString, errno = " << error);

 return 0 ;

 }

 else

 {

  cout<<"Send SucessFul = " << res << "Total Message size"<< size+lengthSize;

  if(res==size+lengthSize)

   flush((ostream&)socket);

  //flush(socket); 


   return 1  ; 

  }
```

This code printing 
Send SucessFul = 11Total Message size 11

But after that its getting stuck in flush(socket) method .Any Idea why its behaving like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cast a socket handle of type `int` to a reference to a `std::ostream` in order to avoid compiler warnings/errors when you tried to hand it to `flush`. I'm surprised it's not crashing.

You can't make more space. The problem isn't you: the problem is that the system's internal buffers are full, and they will drain at their own pace in their own time. You can either poll by trying to `send` over and over till it works (in which case, why are you using non-blocking sockets?), or you use `select`, `poll`, `kqueue`, `epoll`, `libevent`, etc. to sleep till the socket is able to accept more data.

Comment: It will reply `EAGAIN` if it was going to block for any reason. You don't mention your platform; if it's open, just check the kernel source code. Why guess unnecessarily?